# Minizinc seemingly generates invalid FZ code

Tags: compiler-errors, constraint-programming, minizinc

I have the following piece of my model:

```
constraint forall(d in Day, s in Student)
(
  let {
    %groups in day
    array[int] of var opt Group: gid = [g | g in assignment[s] where group_day[g] == d];
    %groups starts in day
    array[int] of var opt Time: gsid = [group_start[g] | g in gid];
    %groups ends in day
    array[int] of var opt Time: geid = [group_end[g] | g in gid];
    %groups durations in day
    array[int] of var opt Time: gdid = [group_duration[g] | g in gid];
    var opt Time: min_start = min(gsid);
    var opt Time: max_end = max(geid);
    var opt Time: sum_dur = sum(gdid);
    var opt int: time = ((max_end - min_start) - sum_dur);
  } in
  wasted_time_units[d,s] = deopt(time)
);
```

I've been trying to get it working by removing `opt` data type from the model, by deopting the whole `gid`, but that threw `model inconsistency detected` error. Fixing and deopting `gid` array worked, but `assignment` is a variable so that produced invalid output. Finally I have arrived to the model shown above, it passed the type check but now I'm getting a cryptic error:

```
Error: Unknown character in line no. 1914
Error: Unknown character in line no. 1914
Error: Unknown character in line no. 1914
Error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting FZ_ID in line no. 1914
```

Below I've attached the FlatZinc output (with line numbers in square brackets):

```
[1913] constraint int_lin_eq([1,1,1,-1],[X_INTRODUCED_894_,X_INTRODUCED_908_,X_INTRODUCED_922_,X_INTRODUCED_955_],0):: defines_var(X_INTRODUCED_955_);
[1914] constraint '-'(X_INTRODUCED_954_,X_INTRODUCED_952_,X_INTRODUCED_956_):: defines_var(X_INTRODUCED_956_);
[1915] constraint '-'(X_INTRODUCED_956_,X_INTRODUCED_955_,X_INTRODUCED_957_):: defines_var(X_INTRODUCED_957_);
[1916] constraint int_ne_reif(X_INTRODUCED_963_,0,X_INTRODUCED_962_):: defines_var(X_INTRODUCED_962_);
```

What does the error mean and how can I avoid it? It seems like minizinc is generating invalid FZ code.

Comment: Which FlatZinc solver do you use? Does it work with some other FlatZinc solver?

Comment: Comparing with the MiniZinc code, it seem like the '-' constraints should have been `int_lin_eq([1, -1, -1], [X_INTRODUCED_954_,X_INTRODUCED_952_,X_INTRODUCED_956_], 0)` instead (there is a int_plus, but for int_minus int_lin_eq is needed). AFAIK, `'-'` is not a valid flatzinc identifier, which is exactly what the error reports.

This should be reported as a bug (preferably with a complete model showing the problem) in the MiniZinc repository: https://github.com/MiniZinc/libminizinc

Comment: @hakank I've checked my model using other solvers, COIN-BC said that my model is inconsistent. Only gecode hangs on invalid flatzinc. I've also checked FZ output using other solvers they did not change the problematic line.

Comment: @Zayenz I've created an issue on github. You can track it here: https://github.com/MiniZinc/libminizinc/issues/588

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by patching minizinc.

Issue was handled here:
https://github.com/MiniZinc/libminizinc/issues/588

After compiling the develop branch, the issue disappeared!